# HTTPS POST in iOS with SSL authentication: cURL?

Tags: ios, object, curl, libcurl

I want to make a HTTPS POST to a server using two PEM files which contain my private key and certificate, and the CACertificate of the server. I've done doing this from a windows application for a while and it works just right. Now I have to do the same from an iOS application on the iPad. It seems the Cocoa Framework does not have functions for this type of requests... any idea on how to do this or how to bring cURL on a iOS device would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I ended up using cURL compiled for iOS 5.1 with openSSL. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) could help with the

[Client certificates](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#client_certificates) methods

```
 If your server requires the use of client certificates, as of v1.8 it
 is now possible to send them with your request.

    // Will send the certificate attached to the identity (identity is a SecIdentityRef)
    [request setClientCertificateIdentity:identity];

    // Add an additional certificate (where cert is a SecCertificateRef)
    [request setClientCertificates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)cert]];

 There is a helper function in ClientCertificateTests.m in the iPhone /
 iPad sample app that can create a SecIdentityRef from PKCS12 data
 (this function only works on iOS).
```

Comment: While I haven't used the certificate functions, ASIHTTPRequest is a great tool for getting your networking going quick and easy. I would recommend starting there.

Comment: Please keep in mind that ASIHTTPRequest is no longer under active development. Only use it if you understand it's inner workings, and are willing to puzzle (a lot) when something breaks on future iOS versions. That said: I am also using ASI in one of my projects for client-certificate authentication, and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @xCoder agree, but ASI is such a nice Framework, even better than AFNetwork